# How to know that application have camera access or not programmatically in iOS8

Tags: camera, ios8, xcode6

My application uses the camera.
In *iOS8* they include a new privacy setting, `Camera`, where the user can manage
use of camera rights for each application.

**Problem:**
If the user didn't allow my application to use camera then how can i know that
My application have no access for camera.
like i can use `ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus` to discover the status of the photolibrary
or `ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus` to know status of *phonebook* access.

**Question:**
How i can know whether my application has camera access or not in iOS8,
so that I may prompt the user to allow camera access for my application?

---

I have below print screen of Photo booth which having same problem
as my application have.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

***When there is no camera access it will only show black screen no message nothing.***

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check [AVAuthorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVCaptureDevice/authorizationStatusForMediaType:) for camera availability and then handle cases accordingly

```cxx
AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
  // authorized
} else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied){
  // denied
} else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted){
  // restricted
} else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){
  // not determined
  [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
    if(granted){
  NSLog(@"Granted access");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Not granted access");
}
  }];
}
```

Comment: Does this work for using the camera to take photos too or just videos? On the developer site, it said something about this method raising an exception if you try to do anything other than record audio/video?