# How to detect, in AIR application, if user has denied access to camera/microphone on ios 8 permissions?

Tags: apache-flex, air, ios8

I am having an AIR application which uses camera/microphone. Need to know if the user has selected "deny access" on IOS 8 ipad, then how the app will be able to detect?

Comment: i dont know much about air application but facing same problem in iOS8 and here is an ans hope it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651863/how-to-know-that-application-have-camera-access-or-not-pragmatically-in-ios8

Comment: Thanks Jageen, for the reference link.

Answer (score 0):

The camera or the microphone are native functions so in AIR in order to access them you need native extensions. If you have a native extension already you should have a method like isSupported that returns true or false if the user allowed access to mic or camera. If you don't have a method like above you need to add one and use native code to check that user give permission for each platform in your case for iOS.

Comment: I guess we need to add a native extension for this, as in AIR till now I don't see any method or check to tell whether user allowed or disallowed camera access.

Comment: Yes you need to add a native extension. One possible native extension can be found here https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-ImagePicker

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely access the microphone without an ANE via [flash.media.Microphone](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html).

I'm guessing `getMicrophone()` would return null if denied:

```
  mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
  if (mic==null) {
    // No microphone found or access denied
  }
```

And this is very old (2009) but here's an [example AIR project](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/using_mic_api.html) using the microphone you could reference.